# how to get the model list from ajax post call to post handler method in asp.net core razor page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to get the model list from the ajax post call to post handler in asp.net core razor pages, I implemented the model and model list first. Later in ajax call I created the model array list and push the information into array list and call the post handler method in the ajax call in asp.net core razor page but not asp.net MVC core.

here is my code I tried

my model:

```
public partial class projectList
    {
        public List<ProjectModel> projectModelList { set; get; }
    }

    public partial class ProjectModel
    {
        public int? User_ID { set; get; }
        public int Projects_ID { set; get; }
        public int? EPR_Summary_ID { set; get; }
        public string Self_Comments { set; get; }
        public int? Self_Rating { set; get; }
        public string Appraiser_Comments { set; get; }
        public int? Appraiser_Rating { set; get; }
        public string Manager_Comments { set; get; }
        public int? Manager_Rating { set; get; }
        public string supervisor_comment { set; get; }
        public int? supervisor_Rating { set; get; }
        public int? ID_Project { set; get; }
    } 

ajax call:

$("#btnProjectSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ProjectData = []; 
 for (max = 0; max < 200; max += 1) {
            ProjectData.push({
                User_ID: 1212,
                Projects_ID: 0,
                ID_Project: 0,
                EPR_Summary_ID: 0,
                Self_Comments: "",
                Self_Rating: 0,
                supervisor_comment: "",
                supervisor_Rating: 0,
                Appraiser_Comments: "",
                Appraiser_Rating: 0,
                Manager_Comments: "",
                Manager_Rating: 0,
            })
        }
      var projectDataList = { "projectModelList":ProjectData };
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/EprEmployee/AddorEditEprEmployee?handler=ProjectSubmit",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(projectDataList),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                if (response == "Sucess") {
                   
                }
                else {
                   
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        }); })

PageModel:

public ActionResult OnPostProjectSubmit([FromForm] projectList projectDataList)
        {
           

            return new JsonResult("Sucess");
        }
```

[image: I'm getting as below as null:]

Comment: can any one help me out please

Answer (score 1):

[FromForm] - Gets values from posted form fields.

[FromBody] - Gets values from the request body.

refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-formatted-data-from-the-request-body

Try to change `[FromForm]` into `[FromBody]` in your code

```
public ActionResult OnPostProjectSubmit([FromBody] projectList projectDataList)
        {
   

            return new JsonResult("Sucess");        }
```

View:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
 <form asp-page-handler="ProjectSubmit" method="post">
            <input type="button"  id="btnProjectSave" name="but1" class="btn btn-default" value ="OnPostProjectSubmit">
          <input id="access_token" type="hidden" name="access_token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['access_token']; ?>" />
        </form>

@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#btnProjectSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ProjectData = []; 
 for (max = 0; max < 200; max += 1) {
            ProjectData.push({
                User_ID: 1212,
                Projects_ID: 0,
                ID_Project: 0,
                EPR_Summary_ID: 0,
                Self_Comments: "",
                Self_Rating: 0,
                supervisor_comment: "",
                supervisor_Rating: 0,
                Appraiser_Comments: "",
                Appraiser_Rating: 0,
                Manager_Comments: "",
                Manager_Rating: 0,
            })
        }
      var projectDataList = { "projectModelList":ProjectData };
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Index?handler=ProjectSubmit",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(projectDataList),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                if (response == "Sucess") {
                   
                }
                else {
                   
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        }); })
        });
    </script>
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I understand and it is working fine :)